# How to write a code for default close button in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to write a code to default close button in `JFrame`. I just want to ask whether "to save the content or not?" using another `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` when click on close button.

Where do I have to write the code? As default close button is not in design of `JFrame`, and no such event found for `JFrame` window too, how can I add event listener to that button?

Comment: *"I am using Netbeans 7.4."*  Given it would be the same code in Eclipse or using any other editor, your IDE is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for a couple of solutions:

1. using a `WindowListener` and overriding the `windowClosing(...)` event to display your option pane.
2. using  a simple API so you only need to provide a message or write an ActionListener for more complicated processing.